# problem getting filterset data originating from a MultipleChoiceFilter

Tags: django, django-filter

Let's say I have the following FilterSet:

```
class ReportFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    type = django_filters.MultipleChoiceFilter(field_name="type", lookup_expr='exact')
```

... and Client submits the following request:

`www.exmaple.com/reports/?type=1&type=2`

I want to be able to get the filterset data from the multiple choice filter as a list, i.e. do something like this:

```
class ReportFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        types = self.data["type"]
```

I would expect `types` to give me a list `[1, 2]` but instead I am getting a string `2`. The strange this is that if I print `self.data` of the filterset, it displays what I am expecting to see

```
<QueryDict: {'type': ['1', '2']}>
```

Any thoughts about what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.data` is a [QueryDict](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects), so you should be able to use the [getlist](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist) method to get a list of all the values

```
types = self.data.getlist("type")
```

Comment: That is great, @Iain. Thank you very much for your help.